# Pass custom props to <InnerBlocks.Content />

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, block-editor

I have a parent component and want to pass some custom props down to the child. The below is my `save` function. I want to pass the number of columns the user chose in the parent component and pass that down to the child.

```
<div {...useBlockProps.save()}>
    <InnerBlocks.Content columns={columns}/>
</div>
```

The above does not work.

Comment: In your `edit` function, can't you just use [`template`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/HEAD/packages/block-editor/src/components/inner-blocks/README.md#template) to set the `columns` prop/attribute? Or were you looking for [block context](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-context/)? Or maybe I didn't get what you mean? 

Comment: @SallyCJ columns in this case is a custom prop and not the wordpress columns. Basically I have a parent component which uses InnerBlocks`template={[]}`and in that child, the number of columns from the parent determines the bootstrap grid. The number of columns is controlled by the user with a range control. If they change it I need to pass that value from the parent down to the child so the child knows how many columns to use. I will take a look at Context and see if that will work here. I just thought there might be an easy way to pass a custom prop straight into `<InnerBlocks.Content/>`

Comment: So I wondered what was your solution? But `InnerBlocks.Content`, as far as I know, doesn't accept any props, so you would want to use the block context. However, 1) The `columns` or whatever attribute needs to be an attribute registered via the parent block's `attributes` passed to `registerBlockType()`, and 2) A block context is not available to `save` in the child block that inherits/consumes the block context.

Comment: @SallyCJ so, what I ended up doing was probably totally overkill but I needed it done so I basically created a custom redux store and used global state to manage it.

Comment: You can use block context. See: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-context/
Then you can access the property in JS and PHP on the child blocks.